# ORA-06550 AND ORA-00917 : COMMA MISSING FOR INSERT STATEMENT

Tags: ora-00917

```
DECLARE 
REG_NO VARCHAR2(20) := & REG_NO;
cursor c1 is select Registration_No ,PROVISIONAL_DIGONOSIS, Remark , Medicine_No ,Dignosis_Date , Precaution Medicine ,No_of_Doses ,Injection_Date ,Status  from Patient_Diagnosis d, Patient_Medicine m , Patient_Injection_Dates  i where d.Registration_No = REG_NO and d.Dignosis_No = m.Dignosis_No  and m.dignosis_no = i.dignosis_no ;

BEGIN
FOR REC1 IN c1
loop
insert into D_DETAIL( reg_no, p_d, remark, m_no, d_date, p_med, doses, i_date, status) values  ( REC1.Registration_No , REC1.PROVISIONAL_DIGONOSIS, REC1.Remark , REC1.Medicine_No, REC1.Dignosis_Date, REC1.Precaution Medicine ,REC1.No_of_Doses , REC1.Injection_Date , REC1.Status );
end loop;
END;


ORA-06550 AND ORA-00917 : COMMA MISSING FOR INSERT STATEMENT IS THE ERROR ....WHAT SHOULD I CHANGE ?
```

Comment: People will be more likely to answer if you format your question and stop yelling.

Comment: There is a comma missing in the insert statement? Check each of your column names has a comma after it. Format your code cleanly and use an IDE to validate your SQL, this should highlight where your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into D_DETAIL( reg_no, p_d, remark, m_no, d_date, p_med, doses, i_date, status) values  ( REC1.Registration_No , REC1.PROVISIONAL_DIGONOSIS, REC1.Remark , REC1.Medicine_No, REC1.Dignosis_Date, REC1.Precaution Medicine ,REC1.No_of_Doses , REC1.Injection_Date , REC1.Status );
```

I'd say

```
REC1.Precaution Medicine
```

should be

```
REC1.Precaution_Medicine
```